# Documenting a Bootstrap Application with React embedded

Tags: reactjs, git, npm, backbone.js, documentation

Our company is slowly transitioning a long-standing product from Backbone to React 15. We are limited to React 15 because the product interacts with other shared products, and the life cycle and build processes we use don't support JSX (as well as other things).

So right now the core application is Backbone, routing, view, models, etc, all handled by the Backbone framework. What we have done is injected React into some of the views, so that while the basic functionality such as the header and footer bars are controlled by Backbone, the internal view, the main user interaction of that particular view is a React application embedded in the view.

All the React code is in one folder, with many, sub-folders, well organized. We want to have documentation for this code only, using something like docz or react-docgen, but those don't seem to work as the git repository and npm roots live at the root of the Backbone app and not the React code folder.

Further complicating the issue is that the React code is in a sub git-repo inside a git-repo (this product has been around a long time).

Any thoughts on how to generate a doc site given these parameters?

Thanks